# MVC 4 EF Html.BeginForm not passing multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm having some trouble getting Html.BeginForm to pass multiple parameters. I need to add any amount of the same item to a wishlist at once, so i'm trying to pass the id and amount to the controller.

My view:

```
@using Website.Models
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions
@model Website.Models.Film

@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Name;
 }
@if (Model != null)

//some code

        using (Html.BeginForm("AddToWishlist", "Wishlist", new { eventId = Model.Id, amount = Model.ticketAmount }, FormMethod.Post))
        {
        <p>Tickets: </p>
            Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ticketAmount, Film.GetFilmSelectItems());
        }

        <input type="button" value="Add to wishlist" @ViewBag.Message/>
    }

else
    {
       <h1><b>@ViewBag.Error</b></h1>      
    }
```

My model:

```
namespace Website.Models
{
    [Table("Film")]
    public class Film : Item
    {

        public string Genre { get; set; }
        public string ImdbLink { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int ticketAmount;

        public Film(int id, string name, string description_en, string description_nl, decimal price, string genre, int locationId)
            : base(id, name, description_en, description_nl, price, locationId)
        {
            this.Genre = genre;
        }

        public Film()
        {

        }

        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetFilmSelectItems()
        {
            const int MAXAMOUNTTICKETS = 10;
            yield return new SelectListItem { Text = "1 ticket", Value = "1" };
            for (int i = 2; i <= MAXAMOUNTTICKETS; i++)
            {
                yield return new SelectListItem { Text = String.Format("{} tickets", i), Value = i.ToString() };
            }
        }
```

WishlistController:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddToWishList(int eventId, int amount)
        {
            cookieCheck.CheckCookie();
            int wishlistId = int.Parse(Request.Cookies["WishList"]["WishlistId"]);
            WishlistItem items = new WishlistItem(wishlistId, eventId, amount);
            wishlistRepo.AddItem(items);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

If i run it and try to add something, 'eventId' is correctly being passed but 'amount' is null. Is it not possible to pass multiple parameters or is the dropdownlist not passing the value?

Comment: You dropdownlist is for `ticketAmount` so the parameter in the POST method needs to be `int ticketAmount` (not `amount`) and remove the route value for the `BeginForm()` method since that only passes the initial value of the model. But why are you not using `public ActionResult AddToWishList(Film model)` and binding to you model?

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the problem. I used to have the AddToWishlist method in a controller for the film page, but that just redirected to a method in the WishlistController so i used that instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set the name of dropdown list to "amount" so it will be included in your post.

something like:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ticketAmount, Film.GetFilmSelectItems(), new { @name="amount"});
```

Comment: That does nothing at all. Fortunately it still generates `name="ticketAmount"` (never attempt to override the `name` attribute generated by the `HtmlHelper`methods)

Comment: just use Html.DroDownList

Comment: Awful advice (and it would not bind to the model)

Comment: well, you are posting a 2 variables(int eventId, int amount), what you can do is change the parameter of your method AddToWishList to Film

Comment: You mean like in my comment to the question :)

Comment: correct, that must be the signature of your method post.